# std::forward and operator()

Tags: c++, templates

I've been looking into writing a static_if for my C++ project, and I stumbled across the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace static_if_detail {

struct identity {
    template<typename T>
    T operator()(T&& x) const {
        return std::forward<T>(x);
    }
};

template<bool Cond>
struct statement {
    template<typename F>
    void then(const F& f){
        f(identity());
    }

    template<typename F>
    void else_(const F&){}
};

template<>
struct statement<false> {
    template<typename F>
    void then(const F&){}

    template<typename F>
    void else_(const F& f){
        f(identity());
    }
};

} //end of namespace static_if_detail

template<bool Cond, typename F>
static_if_detail::statement<Cond> static_if(F const& f){
    static_if_detail::statement<Cond> if_;
    if_.then(f);
    return if_;
}

template<typename T>
void decrement_kindof(T& value){
    static_if<std::is_same<std::string, T>::value>([&](auto f){
        f(value).pop_back();
    }).else_([&](auto f){
        --f(value);
    });
}


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::string myString{"Hello world"};
    decrement_kindof(myString);
    std::cout << myString << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It all makes sense to me, except for one thing: the overloaded operator() in `struct identity`. It takes in a rhs of type T called x, cool and all. But when `identity` is called, nothing is actually passed into identity.

```
template<typename F>
void then(const F& f){
    f(identity());
}
```

Above, f calls identity, but passes nothing onto identity. Yet identity returns the forwarded arguments (in my case, an std::string), and pops the backmost character of the string. 
How is identity returning a forwarded argument, when itself has no arguments passed into it to forward?

Comment: To me it looks like `f` is a function and it's being called with a single argument of type `identity`. In other words, `identity()` is constructing an instance of the `identity` type which is passed to the `f` function.

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/p8SlI9) is what it would look like to construct and call a similar object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f` doesn't call `identity` - `f` is called with an instance of `identity`. Walking through the two cases here:

```
static_if<std::is_same<std::string, T>::value>([&](auto f){
    f(value).pop_back();
}).else_([&](auto f){
    --f(value);
});
```

If `T` is `std::string`, then we instantiate a `statement<true>` whose `then()` invokes the passed-in function with an instance of `identity`. The argument to the first lambda, `f`, will be of type `identity` - so `f(value)` is really just `value` and we do `value.pop_back()`.

If `T` is not `std::string`, then we instantiate a `statement<false>` whose `then()` does nothing, and whose `else_()` invokes the lambda with an instance of `identity`. Again `f(value)` is just `value` and we do `--value`.

---

This is a really confusing implementation of `static_if`, since `f` in the lambda is always an `identity`. It's necessary to do because we can't use `value` directly (can't write `value.pop_back()` since there's no dependent name there so the compiler will happily determine that it's ill-formed for integers), so we're just wrapping all uses of `value` in a dependent function object to delay that instantiation (`f(value)` is dependent on `f`, so can't be instantiated until `f` is provided - which won't happen if the function isn't called).

It would be better to implement it so that you actually pass in the arguments to the lambda.

Comment: Or at least call it `id` or `var` or `safe` instead of `f`.

Comment: This answer sounds about right, +1, but it still leaves the design level purpose of `identity` a mystery. Why can't e.g. the number `42` be passed instead of an instance of `identity`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Added an explanation to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename F>
void then(const F& f){
  f(identity());
}
```

Is more readable as

```
template<typename F>
void then(const F& f){
  f(identity{});
}
```

they are construcing an identity object, not calling one.

The trick here is that the non-dependent parts of a template function must be valid even if the function is never instantiated.

So saying `value.pop_back()` is never valid within the lambda *when value is an integer*.

By passing `identity{}` to exactly one of the `then` or `else` cases, we can avoid this problem.

The statement `f(value)` produces a dependent type.  So it need only be valid when the template `operator()` of the lambda is actually instantiated (there must also be some possibke `f` that makes it valid, but that is a corner case).

As we only instantiate the path the condition tells us to, the `f(value)` can be used almost any way we want, so long as it is valid in the taken branch.

I would have called `f` a better name, like `safe` or `guard` or `var` or `magic` rather than `f`.  The use of two `f`s different contexts in the terse code adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take the case, where your `Cond` is `true` in the `static_if`, hence, the primary template class will be used...

```
template<bool Cond>
struct statement {
    template<typename F>
    void then(const F& f){
        f(identity());
    }

    template<typename F>
    void else_(const F&){}
};
```

Recall, that your calling function is:

```
static_if<std::is_same<std::string, T>::value>
(
   [&](auto f){ //This is the lamda passed, it's a generic lambda
        f(value).pop_back();
    }
).else_(
   [&](auto f){
        --f(value);
    }
);
```

---

In the *applying* function below, `F` is a type of that **generic lambda** *(meaning, you can call `f` with any type)*

```
template<typename F>
void then(const F& f){
    f(identity());
}
```

`identity()` creates an object of type `identity` which is then passed as an argument, to **call** your generic lambda.

```
 [&](auto f){ //This is the lamda passed, it's a generic lambda
        f(value).pop_back();
    }
```

but recall, `f` is an object of type `identity` and has a templated call `()` operator, which basically returns the object passed to it.

---

So, we go like this:

```
void decrement_kindof(std::string& value){
    static_if<std::is_same<std::string, std::string>::value>([&](auto f){
        f(value).pop_back();
    }).else_([&](auto f){
        --f(value);
    });
});
```

Reduced to:

```
void decrement_kindof(std::string& value){
    static_if<true>([&](auto f){
        f(value).pop_back();
    }).else_([&](auto f){
        --f(value);
    });
});
```

Reduced to:

```
void decrement_kindof(std::string& value){
    static_if<true>(
        [&](identity ident){
             auto&& x = ident(value); //x is std::string()
             x.pop_back();
       } (identity())  //<-- the lambda is called

    ).else_(
        [&](auto f){    //This is not evaluated, because it's not called by the primary template of `statement`
            --f(value);
        }
    );   
});
```